# Determining the cardinality of rational set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have two questions, but I don't even know where I can start to solve it, can you give me a hint?

The question is like (Forgive me if MathJax is going wrong):

Determine the cardinality of these sets

a) If X = $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | 1 \leqslant\ x \leqslant\ 3\}$

b) Be $\mathbb{Q}$ like $\mathbb{Q} = \{ p/q | p,q \in \mathbb{Z} q \gt 0\}$

Comment: What do you know about cardinalities?

Comment: that is a beautiful question, loved when I had those! They are really enlighting. I recommend you build yourself bijective maps into either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, since you know the cardinality of those

Answer (score 0):

For one you'll need to make use of the fact that $\omega$ (=$\mathbb{N}$) is bijectively equivalent to $\omega\times\omega$.  A second useful fact is that every real number, except for countably many, has a unique binary expansion.

The last tool in you arsenal is the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).